# iphone sdk delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds in table view loading huge data from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

SendDelegateMessage: delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
If you were not using the touch screen for this entire interval (which can prolong this wait), please file a bug.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { 
    /*
    //NSString *label = [self.aNote length] == 0 ? kDefaultNoteLabel : self.aNote;
    NSString *label = [countriesToLiveInArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //CGFloat height = [label RAD_textHeightForSystemFontOfSize:kTextViewFontSize] + 20.0;
    //return height;
    float lineHeight = [ @"Fake line" sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:15] ].height;


    int numLines = [label sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:15]  constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(250, lineHeight*1000.0f) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation ].height / lineHeight;
    CGSize labelsize =  CGSizeMake(250, (lineHeight*(float)numLines));
    return labelsize.height+10;
     */
    return 100;

}
```

this delegate is the prob.if i comment out this whole function then program works. ad table view use default height but is we return any kind of return value then it shows the message...please help us.

Comment: Hi I have same issue ..have you found any solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374844

Answer (score 1):

Using -heightForRowAtIndexPath: is very expensive for tables with a large number of rows.  It has to be called once for every row in the table, not just the visible rows.  Apple warns about it in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:):

> There are performance implications to
>   using
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
>   instead of the rowHeight property.
>   Every time a table view is displayed,
>   it calls
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on
>   the delegate for each of its rows,
>   which can result in a significant
>   performance problem with table views
>   having a large number of rows
>   (approximately 1000 or more).

Unless you can cache some information to make the method run more quickly, you should probably consider using a fixed row height.

Comment: Hi I have same issue ..have you found any solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374844